# Filter a sql table based on string/json manipulation followed by pivot

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table like this,

```
col1                               col2                            col3      col4
{"id": "123", "name": "xx"}        {"id": "234", "name": "xy"}      123      11-12-2020
{"id": "345", "name": "fx"}        {"id": "534", "name": "ry"}
{"id": "545", "name": "dx"}        {"id": "734", "name": "hy"}
{"id": "823", "name": "ox"}        {"id": "934", "name": "cy"}      223      12-12-2020
{"id": "923", "name": "ox"}        {"id": "834", "name": "vy"}
```

From the above table I just want id from col1 and col2 and one row should have only one id. I want to create another column to distinguish which id it is. And col3 and col4 values will be duplicated row wise, so the output should look like,

```
id     type       col3     col4
123    col1       123      11-12-2020
234    col2       123      11-12-2020
345    col1       123      11-12-2020
534    col2       123      11-12-2020
545    col1       123      11-12-2020
734    col2       123      11-12-2020
823    col1       223      12-12-2020
934    col2       223      12-12-2020
923    col1       223      12-12-2020
834    col1       223      12-12-2020
```

I am using bigqyery to do this, I have tried string manipulation and pivot for it but I am not getting desired output. Looking for some nice way to do it

Comment: If you are using BigQuery, why is the question tagged for Oracle and MySQL?  Should those tags be removed?

Comment: Use [JSON_EXTRACT](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/json_functions#json_extract) for to extract `id`.

Comment: BiqQuery natively supports nested sets, so it's unclear if you data is two rows or 5 rows.  Please include the table definition, or a screenshot from BigQuery.  Because if it is a nested structure, the solution (in part) is to use `UNNEST()`.  If it's not nested, you should expicitly show the values in col3 and col4 as NULL...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
with mydata as (
  select '{"id": "123", "name": "xx"}' as col1, '{"id": "234", "name": "xy"}' as col2, 123 as col3, '11-12-2020' as col4 union all
  select '{"id": "345", "name": "fx"}', '{"id": "534", "name": "ry"}', NULL, NULL union all
  select '{"id": "545", "name": "dx"}', '{"id": "734", "name": "hy"}', NULL, NULL union all
  select '{"id": "823", "name": "ox"}', '{"id": "934", "name": "cy"}', 223, '12-12-2020' union all
  select '{"id": "923", "name": "ox"}', '{"id": "834", "name": "vy"}', NULL, NULL
),
data_with_ordered_column as (select *, row_number() over () as orderby from mydata)
select
  json_value(col1, '$.id') as id,
  last_value(col3 ignore nulls) OVER (ORDER BY orderby) as col3,
  last_value(col4 ignore nulls) OVER (ORDER BY orderby) as col4
from data_with_ordered_column
union all
select
  json_value(col2, '$.id') as id,
  last_value(col3 ignore nulls) OVER (ORDER BY orderby) as col3,
  last_value(col4 ignore nulls) OVER (ORDER BY orderby) as col4
from data_with_ordered_column
order by col4, id
```

[image]

Filling up the missing values in `col3` and `col4` requires a separate column to order by. Skip the `data_with_ordered_column` step and use that column instead if you have one in your table, because `row_number()` produces non-deterministic results.

Comment: Just to expand on @sergeyGreyon's last comment: If you rely on `ROW_NUMBER()` in this way, the non-deterministic nature means that the values in `col3` and `col4` might not *always* be put in the rows you want or expect.  For guaranteed results you *must* have the extra column(s) to deterministically *calculate* which rows get the same values for `col3` or `col4`.